# ASP.net Listview dont show current/new value inserted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a problem in getting new entered record in the ListView.

In my list in ItemTemplate I replaced labels with TextBox. I have also created a button which loops over all the rows in ListView and shows the AcName field in alert message. If I update it (change the text of the AcName) to something else it still shows the record which is already present before, not the new text/value I entered. Below is the code which is working correctly for me but not generating the outcome I want, which is the new value.

HTML Markup

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1"  InsertItemPosition="LastItem" runat="server" >    

  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAcount" Text='<%#Eval("AcName") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
        <asp:TextBox ID="lblAcount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Bind("AcName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNaration" Text='<%#Eval("Naration") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
          <asp:TextBox ID="lblNaration" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Bind("Naration") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPaidAmount" Text='<%#Eval("PaidAmount") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
          <asp:TextBox ID="lblPaidAmount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Bind("PaidAmount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDeductAmount" Text='<%#Eval("DeductionAmount") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
          <asp:TextBox ID="lblDeductAmount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Bind("DeductionAmount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" cssClass="btn btn-info fa fa-trash-o" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteIt"></asp:LinkButton>

        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="False">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Credit Acount"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAcName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Bind("AcName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:ListView>
```

Button handler

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count() - 1

        Dim txtAcNames As TextBox = TryCast(ListView1.Items(i).FindControl("txtAcName"), TextBox)

        Dim msg As String
        msg = "<script language="'javascript'">"
        msg += "alert('" & txtAcNames.Text & "');"
        msg += "</script>"
        Response.Write(msg)

    Next

    'txtTotal1.Text = Paid

End Sub
```

The above code works for me, the problem is when I enter data in the TextBox of the ListView it shows me the old values which is bound to the listview, not the new value that I enter.

what I want is it should show me the new value which I enter at runtime in the ListView TextBox.

Comment: The problem remains unclear to me. You enter data to `lblAcount` textbox, then what do you do that you claim that it displays the old value? Also, does that `ListView` has a datasource? where is it? Please, edit your question adding more information and remove the unnecesary code.

Comment: sir, I have changed labels to textbox to give list a look like editable grid, now the button1 when i click it i shows me in alert all the txtAcNames that are in the listview the problem is when i change the value of a textbox which is lblAcName and press button1 again i still shows me the same old value not the value that i just entered. so is there an solution to that.

Comment: You are alerting the `txtAcName.Text`, but you are changing `lblAcount.Text`, isnt that exactly the issue? The old value you see is in fact from the other textbox (you have both binded to the same property `<%#Bind("AcName") %>`)

Comment: Brother can you add this comment as an answer. I want to +rep you with all of my heart.
I really appreciate your work.

Comment: @MHHasnain, be careful, in your edit you deleted the textbox that is the cause of the problem...

Comment: Ok, and thanks for everything you done for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are alerting the `txtAcName.Text` at `Button1_Click`, but you are changing the value of `lblAcount.Text` at runtime. So, the old value you see is in fact from the other textbox.

Note that you have both textboxes binded to the same property `<%# Bind("AcName") %>`